# No qualifying bean of type 'ThreadPoolTaskExecutor' available

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot 2.2.4 and I'm trying to a custom Executor

Below are the relevant classes

```
@Configuration
@ManagedResource
public class ExecutorConfig {
    @Bean(name = "detailsScraperExecutor")
    public Executor getDetailsAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(1000000);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("detailsScraperExecutor-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

and the following class which tries to use it.

```
@Component
@Profile("!test")
public class DetailsScraper {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DetailsScraper.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("detailsScraperExecutor")
    private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor detailsScraperExecutor;
}
```

When I run the application I get the following error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'detailsScraper': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'detailsScraperExecutor'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor'
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true),
>   @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value="detailsScraperExecutor")}

my application.properties

```
spring.jmx.enabled=false

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://example.com:5432/example
spring.datasource.username=example
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.jpa.open-in-view=false

logging.level.com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit=ERROR

spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize = 30



app.properties.parseaddress.endpoint=http://example.com
```

Even though I have named it `detailsScraperExecutor` Spring can't find it? Why is that?

Comment: Could you post the relevant `app.properties` too?

Comment: @zacran posted it

Comment: I'd check the package names and dependency imports. If those look fine, I'd do a dependency tree and verify the Spring components are there and that the versions are compatible with each other. Hope that helps

Comment: Have you defined custom @ComponentScan ?

Comment: @MykhailoMoskura I have not. Do I need to?

Comment: Nope , just asking .
With what profile do you run ?

Comment: @MykhailoMoskura I did not setup any profiles, I'm only using `@Profile("!test")` for some of my classes since I don't want them to run when I'm running tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to inject the same type of class as declared in configuration but not a higher-level one. But you can use the lower-level one.

```
 @Autowired
 private Executor detailsScraperExecutor;
```

Comment: Thanks, this did solve the issue, but now I'm facing another issue. In one of the methods for the `DetailsScraper` class I have a schedules task, ie ` @Scheduled(fixedDelay=5000)` which every 5 seconds it checks the size of the queue `((ThreadPoolTaskExecutor)  detailsScraperExecutor).getThreadPoolExecutor().getQueue().size()` for some reason the size is always zero even though I know there are threads running for that thread pool.

Comment: Just create bean with type ThreadPoolTaskExecutor in configuration class

Comment: You mean to change the return type? like this? https://pastebin.com/fnXiLPen

Comment: Yes exactly change

Comment: Unfortunately the size of the queue still shows as zero even though there are active threads.

Comment: Let me check and I will answer you